# Copy paste svg elements from illustrator to inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, copy-and-paste

I am trying to copy paste svg elements from illustrator to inkscape, but inkscape rasterize the image rather than pasting the svg code. I know it's possible to paste the svg code [via the built-in xml editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930212/how-to-import-svg-code-into-inkscape), but I'm wondering if there is a solution that would make the process faster / easier (I havent found anything related in the preferences settings). [This is possible in macOS](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Copying_and_pasting_in_Inkscape_creates_pixellated_images_instead_of_copying_the_vector_objects), but is it for windows 10 ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What about using the asset exporter in illustrator to export an svg(s), and then import it in Inkscape? I tried a few different ways with different settings, but can't get it to work either. It seems like Inkscape's clipboard has historically has issues like this.

Comment: Yes, that works too but it's not very practical .. well it seems there is not easy way to do it, so hopefully the inkscape devs will correct it in a future update.

Comment: I've used Inkscape to bulk convert Illustrator documents from .ai to .svg in the past, there are some caveats though Illustrator specific data like symbols for example will be llost as they are not standard svg.